# Plugins won't auto-update on IIS

Tags: plugins, permissions, iis, automatic-updates

Using IIS 6 on XP Server '03, using WP 3.2.1, when I attempt to use the auto-update for my plugins, I receive this message:

> The update process is starting. This process may take a while on some hosts, so please be patient.
>
> Enabling Maintenance mode…
>
> Updating Plugin [Plugin Name] (1/1) 
>   Downloading update from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/polldaddy.2.0.10.zip…
>
> > Unpacking the update…
> >     Installing the latest version…
> >     Removing the old version of the plugin…
> >     Plugin update failed.
> >     An error occurred while updating [Plugin Name]: Could not create directory.
> >     C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/polldaddy/
>
> Disabling Maintenance mode…
>
> All updates have been completed.

When I go to delete a plugin through the WP interface, it removes the plugin from the "*Installed Plugins*" list; however, when I navigate to the directory on the server, I still see the plugin folder in the wp-content folder and I can't open it or delete it. Says, "*Access is denied*".

I don't have any troubles installing new plugins via the WP "*Install Plugins*" web interface.

I've set the `IUSR` & `IIS_WPG` accounts with full control on the wp-content folder and it cascades the permissions down to the other folders. So when I update, it should have the rights to remove/update plugin files.

The weirdest thing to me is if I restart IIS  (`iisreset`), I'm able to auto-update via the web interface just fine & I am then able to delete the "removed" plugin folder that said "Access is denied".

This is frustrating as I don't have time to always stop what I'm doing to reset IIS & wait on it to start back up again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. When auto-updating, certain files would get "locked" somehow stopping the rest of the update process.

Are you using Windows cache extension for PHP by any chance?

Read the following post:
http://ruslany.net/2011/04/wincache-and-wordpress-plugin-upgrade-problem/

Comment: Apparently I am. I checked my WPI and it says WinCache Ext 1.1 for php5.2 is installed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: no problem - this bug drove me nuts before I as able to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: WPI installed it for me originally, so I'm not sure where to extract the files to now.

Comment: thanks! I'll have to wait until the next plugin needs updating, but I'm pretty sure it's fixed. I was able to delete a plugin without a problem.

Comment: Your answer resulted in a big win for me with the execs!  Thanks!